# How to pass datetime value into a custom SQL in Yii?

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following code:

```
$criteria->addCondition(<<<'SQL'
    (t.create_date BETWEEN ":start_date" AND ":end_date") OR
    (t.pay_date BETWEEN ":start_date" AND ":end_date")
SQL
);
$criteria->params[':start_date'] = $additionalParams['createOrPayBetween'][0].' 00:00:00';
$criteria->params[':end_date'] = $additionalParams['createOrPayBetween'][1].' 23:59:59';
```

But it doesn't work. For some reason :start_date and :end_date stays as it is and parameters aren't propagated. How do I use *custom* SQL with *datetime* values propagated with bo SQL-injection threat in Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quotes around params, so your query params is just strings (like `BETWEEN "anystring" AND "anotherstring"`, don't use quotes:

```
$criteria->addCondition(<<<'SQL'
   (t.create_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date) OR
   (t.pay_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date)
SQL
);
```

Yii will automatically adds quotes to params